# Position two divs next to each other

Tags: html, css, position

How can I position the two divs below next to each other?

```html
<div style="display:inline;float:left;">
  <img src="Imagens/myimg.png" />
</div>';

<div style="display:inline;float:left;">
  <img src="Imagens/myimg2.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: They look next to each other to me

Comment: Consider using [placeholders](placehold.it) for images that are not hosted

Comment: You can't use `display:inline` and `float:left;` at the same time. They are *mutually exclusive* layout methods.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: make sure your images can fit on one line, otherwise if they're too wide they will show up on 2 lines despite the `display: inline` and `float: left`

Comment: `body { display: flex; }` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below:

```
<div style="width:400px;">

  <div style="float:left;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150"/>
  </div>

  <div style="float:right;">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150"/>
  </div>

</div>
```